# Symfony2: How can I send the current user to the edit form without overwritting the entity to edit?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Okay, so I need to access the current user's role in the form in order to query different things according to the role, it works just fine when creating a new user. Send the logged in user to the form as $options... however, I've noticed when editing the form, the $data option inside $options, it's the entity to edit...

How can I send the current user along the entity to edit without overwriting any of them?

I was trying this:

```
$current_user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('user_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
            'method' => 'POST',
            'data' => $current_user,
        ));
```

but the 'data' option seems to overwrite the $entity I send above.

How can I send both?

Comment: Add the user to the entity, not the data.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "add the user to the entity", the entity to edit is also a user instance.

Comment: So you only need to expose the current user to the form?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think to achieve a higher level of quality you would need to declare your form type as a service and receive the SecurityContext object as a dependency, like this:

```
services:
    form.type.user:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type\UserType
        arguments: ["@security.context"]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: user_type }
```

And declare the form type like this:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType {


    private $securityContext;

    public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }
}
```

That way you can access the user through the SecurityContext object, which will be injected automatically by Symfony.

Create the form like this:

```
$form = $this->createForm($this->get('form.type.user'), $data);
```